# Natural Gas Grill PSI/WC Question

Tags: natural-gas

I recently purchased a natural gas grill after having a local gas company run an underground natural gas line to an area in the back yard. I'm having some issues with low flame though, and wanted to get some insight from those with a natural gas grill.

The line going to the grill area is at 2 PSI that they have ran underground, prior to being attached to any grill hose/parts they then put a converter/regulator to bring it down from 2 PSI to 1/2 PSI or 14'' WC. It is then attached to the grill hose, that routes it to the grills natural gas regulator that it came equipped with that pushes it down to 4'' WC or 0.144 PSI, which is supposed to be the standard operating pressure for the grill.

However, in the grill manual, it states that the natural gas line should only operate at a pressure of 7'' WC prior or 1/4 PSI prior to going to the natural gas regulator that came with the grill, that converts it to 4''WC or 0.144 PSI.

My question is, since they hooked it up with a converter from 2 PSI to 1/2 PSI or 14'' WC before it hitting the grills natural gas regulator (instead of a converter that brings it to 1/4 PSI or 7'' from 2 PSI), and it's stating that it should operate at a pressure of 7'' WC or 0.25 PSI when it gets to the natural gas regulator on the grill would this cause me to have a low flame on the grill?

Or is it simply stating I need at least a pressure of 7'' WC before it hits the natural gas regulator that came with the grill, thus not the reason I have a low flame?

I've checked the orifice size and they are 1/16 which is what's needed for each burner for around 10,000 BTU. I've also checked the burners to make sure they are clear and no debris is in them.

The only other thing I can think of if the problem above isn't causing it is that the natural gas regulator that came with the grill is defective.

Here's the link to the grill for reference: https://www.samsclub.com/p/members-mark-ss304-deluxe-stacked-stone-4-burner-grill-island-with-griddle/P03013126

Comment: Are you certain that you have the natural gas version as opposed to the propane version?

Comment: @Mark, 14" WC implies a propane regulator. That regulator plus a propane regulator on the unit itself would imply lots of natural gas and too much heat.

Comment: I can't find any pressure/flow throttling overpressure safety device for gas. It's either pressure relief blasting gas into the atmosphere or the flow is entirely stopped. My instinct is that the natural gas line is to blame. How do you know that the pressure behind that regulator is 2 psi? Was the gas line sized for sufficient flow? How did they backfill over the trench? Did they unceremoniously dump fill littered with chunks of rock into the trench?

Comment: The gas company that hooked it up, took off the nozzle and showed me how fast the NG was coming out, without it hooked up to the grill, you can hear it coming out at a pretty high speed.

Comment: I'm certain it is a NG grill as i've taken a look at the orifices and they were 1/16, and look at the serial number, the box it came with, the label, and all that jazz. I dk of any other way to verify that its the NG version.

Comment: @popham They dug a trench, which is where the pool pipes were going, and then also ran a underground gas pipe in that trench as well, but the installer showed me how fast the natural gas was coming out of the natural gas pipe before he reinstalled the grill line that came with the grill

Comment: I have zero intuition for what 1/2 psi sounds like. I wouldn't trust a gauge because sufficient static pressure can become insufficient under your necessary flow rate (a low pressure reading implies there's a problem, but a normal pressure reading could also indicate a problem). You could try another appliance (use another that you own, borrow one, or pick up something like https://www.amazon.com/onlyfire-Natural-Propane-Fireplace-Firepit/dp/B01M1BFEF0/).